# scala programming question about importing other objects

Tags: scala

I am working on the examples of [99 scala problems](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/).The question p11 i.e [Modified run-length encoding](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/p11.scala). On the second line, it imports the object from p10 code "import P10.encode". My question here is when it gets into the below line of code

```
encode(ls) map { t => if (t._1 == 1) t._2 else t }
```

I am aware that it maps P10 encode definition but how does it know from where it should get the t value? Does it work on the output such as if the output of p10 is List((1,1), (2,4), (1,3)) for the input encode(List(1,4,4,3)) or something else? Please enlighten me

Comment: If `encode(ls)` returns a `List` of, say, 3 elements, then `map()` will invoke its anonymous function 3 times. Each time it does, `t` will be given a different value from the list.

Answer (score 2):

so the `t` is just an identifier for an anonymous function parameter.

I am assuming that `encode(ls)` returns `List[(Int, Int)]` so that means that `map` has the following signature `map[B](f : ((Int, Int)) => B)`

this means it requires a function from `Int` (which is what's in the list) to some other type.

`t => if (t._1 == 1) t._2 else t` is a literal for a function that takes one parameter called `t` (the compiler can infere that it has to be an `(Int, Int)` due to the literal being in the parameter position of `map` on a `List[(Int, Int)]`) and and returns a single `Int` yielding a `List[Int]` after the `map`

really it could also have been  `x => if (x._1 == 1) x._2 else x` it's just a local name

EDIT: Added parens for the int tuple in map as per comment. woops

Comment: Technically the signature of map would look more like `map[B](f : ((Int, Int)) => B)` (note the extra parentheses around the tuple).